# User is null even after token is validated

Tags: api, asp.net-core, jwt, claims

I have a web API designed in Asp.Net core 2.1 and I am using self-signed tokens using the multi-tenant tokens.

The token is successfully authenticated and by the `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller. Now I am trying to access the subject inside the same using `User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value`.

The value of `User` is null even after the token is authenticated. I am expecting the claims from the validated token.

I could not find the reason for the `User` value being null. I could not find the reason for the `User` value being null.
What could be wrong?

Comment: 1. How do you know "The token is successfully authenticated"?  2. Please show us the related code including the Startup and the controller.

Comment: I was able to tell that it is authorized because endpoint in the controller with `[Authorize]` attribute is able to respond and return data. I was able to resolve this by accessing the name from the `IHttpContextAccessor`. I injected `IHttpContextAccessor` in the controller and pulled in using `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.name`. But I still do not understand why the user is not in `system.principal.identity.User`.

Comment: There's no such a built-in `system.principal.identity.User` in ASP.NET Core at all. The user principal should be stored in `HttpContext.User`.